# useMemo not updating if nested value in object is undefined | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
  setObj({val1: 1, val2: undefined});
}, []);

const val3 = useMemo(() => {
  return obj?.val2;
}, [obj?.val2]);
```

The `useMemo` is not updated once the `obj` is set with new value on `useEffect`. Is to more logical to have a dependency array like: `[obj]`? Or should it get updated since `obj.val2` is set to `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first render:
obj?.val2 evaluates to `undefined` because obj is `undefined`.

In the second render:
obj?.val2  evaluates to `undefined` because obj.val2 is `undefined`.

If you want the memoized value to be recomputed when whole `obj` changes, the use `obj` otherwise `obj?.val2` is fine.

Look at this :

```
export default function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    setObj({ val1: 1, val2: 3 });
    setTimeout(() => {
      setObj({ val1: 1, val2: 3 });
    });
  }, []);

  const val3 = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("called");
    return obj?.val2;
  }, [obj]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{JSON.stringify(val3)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Above will recompute `val3` even if val2 was set to the same value 3. That is because dependency array consists of `obj`. If you replace it with `obj?.val2`, the value is only computed twice.

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-darkness-wjyhge?file=/src/App.js:0-553)